# ListPicker Mutiple SelectionMode SelectionChanged not firing

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I am using  ListPicker with Multiple SelectionMode WP7.1. In the list of items displayed,I have 3 items like A,B and None.If the user select A and B,then if he select None then selected items A and B has to do unselected automatically.I observed that SelectionChanged Event is not firing for each item selected in list
Please help

Comment: As your question is related to your code, can you post your code here to make it easier to answer..?

Comment: you should have that logic in your viewmodel.